# dynamic nodejs router calls that check var vs function name?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

not sure how to word this but is it possible to have vars passed through as param but in some cases have function calls like the following?

```
router.get('/user/:id', function(){
    if(req.params.id.toLowerCase() == 'edit') next();
    //DISPLAY USER
});

router.get(/user/edit/:id', editUser);
```

or do is it only possible to have it like

```
router.get('/user/:id', displayUser);
router.get('/user/:id/edit', editUser);
```

this way works fine but looks better I find having it set the other way on the userend

Comment: Try it - see what happens.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Express 4.0, you would also have access to the router.param() function, shown here:

http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.param

This allows you to create a function devoted to doing something with a parameter whenever/wherever in your site it appears. For example, lets say in my application I have a parameter user_id, which is a pkid in a database every single time it shows up. I could then do this:

```
app.param( 'user_id', function( request, response, next, id )
{
  db.find( id, function( err, results )
  {
    if( !err )
    {
      request.params.user = results;
      next();
      return;
    }
  } );
  next();
} );
```

But, this only works if you have parameters that are always mapped to the same thing. If the parameter name changes, or the value contained by the parameter changes, this won't help you.

Answer (score 1):

displayUser is in fact a function or it should be ;) and yes your first assumption is almost correct except that you are missing req,res and next parameters in your function call, if is in fact a middleware, if not next is not needed. i would recommend you to read about connect style middlewares and some about javascript too